# Unused UK visa and applying for a new one

Tags: visas, uk

I got my son a 6-month UK visa. Now I am concerned that he might be unable to take the flight because school has already started and his visa remained unused. Is it possible that when he applies for a new one next time he will be provided with a new one, or will there be any complications due to the unused visa?

Answer (score 1):

A six month visa would give you six months time. If he received the visa say June 1st then he can travel after June 1st and must leave before November 30th (and if there is a limit for the length of stay, that applies as well).

The unused visa doesn't matter if you apply for a new one. But you got a visa, you paid your fees which are supposed to cover all the cost that the UK had to issue your visa, so there is no reason why you wouldn't get another visa.

It *might* be that you can't apply for a time that overlaps with your still valid visa. So in my example, if your son wanted to travel November 25th to December 5th, that *might* be a problem and you should check that.